# Android profiler not supported for Kitkat devices/google glass in android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat, profiler, android-studio-3.0

From android studio 3.0 `Android Monitor` turned to `Android profiler`. But, when using google glass device or other android kitkat devices it's showing below message in android profiler window:

`Device not supported. Android profiler requires a device with API 21(Lollipop) or higher.`

What's the solution for Kitkat devices to use the latest Android Profiler once android studio 3.0 available for update in stable version?

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but KitKat is breaking when I'm trying to build to emulators and devices from Studio 3.0 preview; the failure comes when I upgrade to using gradle 3.0.0-alpha6. Is it possible that Kitkat got dropped all together?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Android Device Monitor (Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor) is still available.

I am having difficulty running its memory monitor, although it does seem to update its heap size in real-time.

It also gives you access to useful icons such as "Dump HPROF file" and "Run Garbage Collector".

The HPROF files can still be analyzed using Android Studio by dragging them into the editor region.

Comment: Android studio 3.1.3 version Android Device Monitor isn't avilable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the advanced profiling, follow these steps:
Select Run > Edit Configurations.
Select your app module in the left pane.
Click the Profiling tab, and then check Enable advanced profiling.
For more details, check [Measure App Performance](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem: even if I enable advanced profiling I cannot perform app performance on pre-lollipop devices.