# Android Monitor for android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've just updated Android Studio 3.0 today. But turns out Android Monitor is missing.[image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html

Almost developers have to support a wide range of devices. But Android Studio 3.0 only support API 21 and above

[image]

My question is: do we have any alternative tools to do this? I just don't want to use android studio 2.3.3 along side with Android Studio 3.0

Comment: That's why you never update your Android studio. Took me half a day to run an older project after updating to 2.3.3. Ended up having to disable Instant run, the *awesome new feature they added*. I feel your struggle, hopefully someone will provide a good answer here.

Comment: The profiler is only for device stats like cou usage and memory usage, logcat is syill around for text-based debug. If you really beed the device monitor you either need a lollipop device or AS 2.3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android profiler not supported for Kitkat devices/google glass in android studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143997/android-profiler-not-supported-for-kitkat-devices-google-glass-in-android-studio)