# Android Profiler alternative for older devices

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 3.0 Android Monitor was replaced with Android Profiler, but it can't be used for pre-Lollipop devices.
Is there a way to watch CPU and memory real time data for older devices in Android Studio 3.0? I tried Android Device Monitor (under Tools->Android) but I can't find such a tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android profiler not supported for Kitkat devices/google glass in android studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143997/android-profiler-not-supported-for-kitkat-devices-google-glass-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

actually I was havign the same problem. The solution is to use the Android Device monitor, you can find it:
*AndroidStudio* -> *Tools* -> *Android* -> *Android Device Monitor*

### Procedure

1. Restart adb, so that android device monitor can capture the device. You should see your device listed on ***Devices*** tab
2. After this select the process for your app, it should have the same package name.
3. Initiate method profiling recording by pressing [image]
4. At this point your should run the app or activity that you would like to profile, when you're finished to use the app press[image]
5. After stop you should have a new tab showing the trace file for captured process.

[image]
There you have it, now all you have to do is find the heavy cpu methods and look for optimization.

More reading:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html
- https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/android-method-profiling-with-ddms/